# valueChanges input show's but doesn't save

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm looking to save a stock number brought through on change when a medication is selected - the valueChanges updates correctly and shows the correct number, however onSubmit the field is empty and doesn't save the expected value.

TS

```
initForm() {
this.addDrugAuditForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  serviceUserId: this.serviceUserId,
  medication: ['', Validators.required],
  theoreticalStock: ['', Validators.required],
  actualStock: ['', Validators.required],
  error: new FormControl(),
  reportedDate: [ this.today, Validators.required]
});

this.addDrugAuditForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  this.selectedMedicationToAudit = this.serviceUsersMedication.find(item => {
    return item.id === val.medication;
  });

  if (this.selectedMedicationToAudit) {
    const stock = fetchStockForMedication(this.selectedMedicationToAudit, this.stockDictionary);
    this.selectedMedTheoreticalStock = stock.quantity || 0;
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
  <label>Theoretical Stock*</label>
  <input id="theoreticalStock"
         type="text"
         formControlName="theoreticalStock"
         [value]="selectedMedTheoreticalStock"
         class="form-control"
         >
</div>
```

Comment: Can you maybe create a Stackblitz, that would make it easier to help you and reproduce your problem.

Comment: You don’t need that [value] on your input. You can use the formControl (that is what they are for). So something like this.addDrugAudotForm.get(‘ theoreticalStock’).setValue(stock.quantity || 0)

Comment: @MikeOne that's perfect, thanks for your help!